# Symfony 3.4 Authentication using name, login and password

Tags: symfony, authentication

I would like to create authentication using name, login and password. Currently, I used the documentation [enter link description here](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/entity_provider.html#what-do-the-serialize-and-unserialize-methods-do)

but there is only login and password used. It seems to me that I should extend one of the token classes, but I do not know if it will be a good approach to the topic.

---edit

I addded to my UserRepository this methog, works, but I don't think, that is good idea

```
public function loadUserByUsername($login)
{
    $name = trim($_POST["_name"]);
    $result = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->where('u.login = :login AND u.name= :name')
        ->setParameter('login', $login)
        ->setParameter('name', $name)
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
    return $result;

}
```

Comment: maybe an injection to the service request, in which these fields are sewn in and searching by name and login in the loadUserByUsername method will solve the problem ...
just how to inject there request ...

Comment: You should try this documentation guide https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/custom_password_authenticator.html

Comment: I added a solution, but probably not the best